# How to avoid renaming Oledbconnection data source

Tags: oledbconnection

When transfering file to another location i always need to change the source or directory..

```
Dim cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Renz\Desktop\FINAL\Database\AuditDB.mdb")
```

Is there a way I can avoid that?

Comment: Is the VB.NET? How are you accessing the database, website, window forms, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a path relative to your applications location, e.g.

```
Dim cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database\AuditDB.mdb")
```

Where in this example I am presuming that your database is stored in a folder called `Database` in the same folder as your program.

Comment: it worked thanks,, but when i publish the file its not working